# Issue : Umbraco Content Nodes automatically adds duplicate nodes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

We have a Umbraco website integrated with ASP.NET MVC. Suddenly, we ran into issues where content nodes are duplicating itself randomly.

In order to find the issue, we recently stood up a fresh Umbraco version 7.1.4 website without any MVC stuff. We added some content nodes inside the Home node last week.

Today, when I logged in to the Umbraco backoffice, I saw more than 100 duplicate Home Nodes.

We feel like there is some setting on Umbraco that tells the application to add the duplicate nodes.

If anyone has solution to this issue, that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Check the property tab of the duplicates to check which user has created those.

If it's admin, you probably have some ApplicationEventHandler or node creation process gone wrong in your code.

Comment: When I look at the properties tab, the user is the umbraco admin. However, the "Link to document" value is "Oops: this document is published but is not in the cache(internal error). As per the ApplicationEventHandler, we just used whatever comes with Umbraco download file. We don't have any custom code written. I have tried deleting all the duplicate nodes on the database and even clearing the cache. When I login next time, I again see lots of duplicate pages.

Comment: Then it might be a examine cache issue.  Try rebuilding the cache from the developer node/examine index tab.

Comment: Thanks dampee. How do I rebuilt the examine cache?

Comment: 2 ways, stop the website and delete the App_Data/Temp/Examine folder, then restart the website and publish a node.  Or, much easier, from the backend.  Open the developer section, go to the examine tab, open the first section.